# Change update-java-alternatives prio

Tags: java

```
karl@karl-Dell-Precision-M3800:~$ update-java-alternatives -l
java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64       1081       /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
java-6-oracle                  1085       /usr/lib/jvm/java-6-oracle
java-7-oracle                  1083       /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle
java-8-oracle                  1086       /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
java-9-oracle                  1084       /usr/lib/jvm/java-9-oracle
```

I'd like to set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64 as 1090. I've tried update-alternative install but it won't change.

Answer (score 4):

You can either override the automatic choice based on the priority value by setting the alternative manually:

```
update-java-alternatives --set java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64
```

---

Or you can change the priority of each entry by manually editing the appropriate configuration file in `/usr/lib/jvm`, in your case that would be `/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo`.

Open it in your favourite text editor as root and change the line

```
priority=1081
```

to your needs. It should be near the top of the file, probably line 3.

Comment: Editing the `/usr/lib/jvm/.java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64.jinfo` was perfect!

Comment: If it solved your problem, please consider accepting this answer by clicking the grey check button on its left... but as a 550+ rep user, you should know that ;-)

Comment: JDK added to `/opt` do not have `.jinfo` file. What is the workaround for such a cases?